# Make Flex TextInput show no prompt on empty String

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am using a s:TextInput in Flex 4.5. It shows it's prompt text if the underlying text value is null or empty String. Does anybody know if I can make either don't show the prompt on empty String or even show a different prompt?
I already found a way by extending the TextInput class and overriding some of the methods but I am still hoping anyone here knows an easier way ;-)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'show a different prompt'? Do you want to change the prompt text? And if you remove the prompt property, doesn't it remove the prompt text also?

Comment: I have two cases:  
1. text == null => show the prompt;  
2. text == ""   => don't show the prompt (or different one).  
Just binding the prompt to a get function doesn't work because the TextInput doesn't load it every time it want's to show the prompt.

Comment: I see. So the main problem is binding to a getter? If so, let me know so i can give you a proper answer, with some code.

Comment: Of course I can just bind the text to a property and set that property when my case changes. Should have thought of that right away but I tend to get a little blind when weekend is close ;-) You can post that as an answer if you want to. If not I do it myself as soon as I am abble to (must wait 8 hours). Thanks a lot for getting me think.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help. However, you could use a public property, of course, but then you'd be exposing it to change from outside, and you might not want this, so a getter might be more suited in your case, because it exposes a read-only property. I'll post an answer with this concept so you can see exactly what I mean.

Comment: I just used a private property. They can be bindable as well and nothing is exposed. The few logic is handled in the script block for now so no problem there. But I'm interested in your idea because I maybe should move this into a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so based on the comments, here it is:
You store the current prompt value in a private variable, like so:

```
private var _inputPrompt:String = "";
```

Then you create a getter, so the value is accessible from outside of this class:

```
public function get inputPrompt():String
{
    return _inputPrompt;
}
```

Now you can bind **inputPrompt** anywhere you need it, however, the problem is the getter won't be recalled once the private value changes. You can fix this very easily: Create an update method, for example like so:

```
public function updateInputPrompt(value:String):void
{
    _inputPrompt = value;
}
```

Ok, nothing fancy so far. I'm guessing this is the point where you are right now. In order to "force" the getter to be recalled, you have to bind it to an event, like so:

```
[Bindable(event="inputPromptUpdated")]
public function get inputPrompt():String
{
    return _inputPrompt;
}
```

Finally, you can simply dispatch this event when the value is update (i.e. in the **updateInputPrompt** method):

```
public function updateInputPrompt(value:String):void
{
    _inputPrompt = value;
    dispatchEvent("inputPromptUpdated"); // For binding
}
```

This way, the getter will be recalled every time you dispatch that event.

Hope this helps. Have a great day, and a great weekend!